# Sign in the equation to find Green's functions in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, propagator

Studying in an introductory course to field theory I came across the equation useful for determining a green function given the equation of motion of the theory dealt with. In the appendix of the book [Relativistic Quantum Fields Bjorken Drell](https://it.scribd.com/doc/316947383/Relativistic-Quantum-Fields-Bjorken-Drell-1965)  I found the following formulations
[image]

my question is: why is the sign different in relationships? Shouldn't that relationship be independent of the equation of motion discussed? 
What I would write is

$(\Box-m^2)G_F(x-y)=\delta^4(x-y)$

$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)S_F(x-y)=\delta^4(x-y)$

If the relationship $A(x)G(x-y)=\delta^4(x-y)$ for the equation of motion $A(x)\Psi=0$ was universal for any equation of motion.

Comment: It's just a matter of convention. You could easily find the same results, up to a sign, using the standard definition without the minus sign

Comment: I had thought this, but you mean that in the final definition of the propagator it would remain $S_F(p)=-\frac{1}{(p^2-m^2)}$ ? 
I've always found  $S_F(p)=\frac{1}{(p^2-m^2)}$ in literature

Comment: No, the propagator would have both a positive sign, it's the relation between them that changes, namely $$S_F = -(i\not \partial+m)\Delta _F $$

Comment: okay, I understand, but therefore it is not correct to say that, given the generic operator that defines the equation of motion $A(x)$, $A(X)\Psi=0$, 
the relative green function is found with the relationship $A(x)G(x-y)=\delta^{4}(x-y)$ ? 
in this case I would find, following as I wrote at the bottom of the question, 
the KG operator with the wrong sign.

Comment: Yes, that's true. There need not to be a zero in the equation of motion, you can have even a source term like $$\hat{L}\phi(x) = g(x)$$ the green function will still be $$\hat{L}G(x-y)=\delta(x-y)$$

Comment: Thank you. I found a detailed description of the problem in the first volume of the B.D. that I mentioned for those interested. Bjorken-Drell: "Relativistic quantum mechanics".